# how to class component to functional components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, treelist

I have some state and their setState also. but I wanna convert to the class component to the functional component but I don't understand in setState how to do that

**state:**

```
   constructor(posts) {
    super(posts);
    this.state = {
      data: posts,
      searchResultArray: [],
      cursor: {},
      currentResultIndex: 0,
    };
    this.onToggle = this.onToggle.bind(this);
  }
```

**SetState**:

plz, look **this.setState** my point is how to convert functional components in those setState ? i dont understand how to multiple state in **this.setState** function. can i do this in functional components?

```
  onTextChange = (e) => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    let term = e.target.value;
    let tempObj = {};
    let results = [];
    let newData = {};
    if (term.length > 0) {
      results = getSearchResult(term, data);
      console.log(results);
    }
    if (results.length > 0) {
      tempObj = setSearchResult(data, results, 0);
      newData = tempObj.data;
    } else {
      newData = data;
    }
    this.setState({
      searchResultArray: results,
      data: newData,
      searchTerm: term,
    });
  };
  onBtnClick = (e) => {
    const { data, searchResultArray, currentResultIndex } = this.state;

    let index = 0;
    let tempObj = {};
    if (e.target.id === "prev") {
      index = currentResultIndex - 1;
      tempObj = setSearchResult(data, searchResultArray, index);
      this.setState({
        data: tempObj.data,
        currentResultIndex: index,
        cursor: tempObj.cursor,
      });
    }
    if (e.target.id === "next") {
      index = currentResultIndex + 1;
      tempObj = setSearchResult(data, searchResultArray, index);


      this.setState({
        data: tempObj.data,
        currentResultIndex: index,
        cursor: tempObj.cursor,
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

To change this to a functional component, you should make use of the useState hook.
Basically, useState hook is used to store a state variable and update it later, you do not need to use the class state anymore.
There are 2 ways to turn your state into useState, either by using a big useState, that will store a variable similar to your current state. Or you could cut down your state into small pieces (which is much cleaner and the way you should do it in functional react)

Here's how you would do it:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(posts);
const [searchResultsArray, setSearchResultsArray] = useState();
const [cursor, setCursor] = useState();
const [currentResultIndex, setCurrentResultIndex] = useState();
```

Then, in your onClick:

```
onBtnClick = (e) => {
const { data, searchResultArray, currentResultIndex } = this.state;

let index = 0;
let tempObj = {};
if (e.target.id === "prev") {
  index = currentResultIndex - 1;
  setCurrentResultIndex(index)
  tempObj = setSearchResult(data, searchResultArray, index);
  setData(tempObj.data)
  setCursor(tempObj.cursor)
}
if (e.target.id === "next") {
  index = currentResultIndex + 1;
  setCurrentResultIndex(index)
  tempObj = setSearchResult(data, searchResultArray, index);
  setData(tempObj.data)
  setCursor(tempObj.cursor)
 }
};
```

Comment: Hey, jeremynac. thx you so much. I have done it yesterday as you said almost but one setState I don't do the same as you said. that's why didn't work properly. now I just change as you said and now perfectly working. thx you very much.

Comment: This is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/react-treebeard-custom-search-forked-gn6vqb?file=/src/TreeView.js:1791-1826

thx you jeremynac.